# Recently i installed android studio 2.3.2 with all sdk update, but not able to open emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-2.3

Recently I installed android studio 2.3.2 
with all SDK updates, but I am still not able to open emulator, 
when I run app on Android Virtual Device the emulator pops up and closes, in task bar its shows app is completely loaded.

Comment: when you launch Emulator in console error will be print. please post the error

Comment: Have a look at this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/42856284/5832648

Comment: @8hubham i seen that comment but in my sdk tools android emulator is already 26.0.3

Comment: @Mohammadnabil u mean in logcat.. its blank no error is showing

Comment: yes, Open SDK, and update HAXM and install intel HAXM drivers. may helps

Comment: I too face this problem many times, and I h'v just install the  drivers and its goes fine.

Comment: @Mohammadnabil HAXM i hav latest version 6.0.6 i tried uninstalling and installing again it didnt work.   what u mean by driver system drivers?

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

Comment: @Mohammadnabil its showing an error in event log                            
                               StatusChangeListenerException: Failed to update status to RUNNING: HAXM setup failed!